# How to type constructor/factoryless mixins?

Tags: typescript, types, mixins

We have a legacy JavaScript library that makes extensive use of mixins, but without the usual factory-function-plus-class-expression pattern; instead, [it uses `Object.assign` in the constructor](https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/1d1a927628241f72a464e31f708f4b35ffbd3ab1/core/block.ts#L267) to mix properties into each instance directly.  Simplified:

```
const blockTypes = {
  TYPE_A: {
    mixinMethod1: function(/*...*/) {/*...*/},
    mixinMethod2: function(/*...*/) {
      this.blockMethod();
      this.mixinMethod1();
    }
  },
  TYPE_B: {/*...*/},
  // Arbitrarily more, including ones supplied by
  // countless developers using this library.
}

class Block {
  constructor(type: string) {
    // Other init here.
    Object.assign(this, blockTypes[type]);
  }
  blockMethod() {/*...*/}
}

class BlockSubclass extends Block {/*...*/}
```

The code defining `Block` and `BlockSubclass` has been converted to TypeScript; now I am attempting to convert the code that defines `blockTypes` (and more particularly the mixins therein).  At the moment this is typed `blockTypes: {[key: string]: BlockDefinition}`, where `type BlockDefinition = any`, but this is *somewhat unsatisfactory*.

What type should `BlockDefinition` be so that `tsc` understands that each entry of `blockTypes` to be a separate 'type' that will be mixed into `Block` (and subclasses thereof)?  Specifically, such that in methods defined in `TYPE_A`, `this` would have a type equivalent to `class TypeA extends Block { /* TYPE_A's methods */ }`.

Bonus: Is there a nice way to indicate that particular `TYPE_X` is a mixin for `BlockSubclass` in particular?  (I understand that, per the Liskov Substitution Principle such a type would not strictly speaking be assignable to `BlockDefinition`; I'm just wondering if there's some way to avoid having to cast `(this as BlockSubclass)` each time a method on `TYPE_X` wants to call a `BlockSubclass` method.)

Notes:

- There are various things about the existing design that are not exactly delightful; unfortunately there's too much existing code out in the wild for us to be able to rearchitect it—at least not without a long, carefully-planned transition.
- The `Block` class and its methods do not attempt to access any properties/methods not defined on `Block`, but some of the mixins override the default values/implementations rather than merely adding new properties.

Comment: Does `BlockSubclass` choose the `type` of `Block` by passing a constant into `super(…)`?

Comment: I guess adding `as const` to `blockTypes` and putting `(this: Block & (typeof blockTypes)['TYPE_A'], …)` for the parameter list of every mixin method would work.

Comment: The `BlockSubclass` constructor passes its own `type` parameter to `super()`.  A block's `type` and class (`Block` vs. `BlockSubclass`) are orthogonal.

I don't think `as const` will work because developers can create new block types dynamically at runtime.

The goal of typing the block type definitions is to catch errors in the definitions—in our examples, and in developer's own entries.  I'm not worried about errors in _use_ of those definitions, because our library treats all the objects as `Block` (or `BlockSubclass`) and (largely) ignores any additional properties.